# Is it possible to change the probability of a choice in corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm not sure if it is possible but I want to change the probability of what "choice" is done. I have a code something like this:

```
({move, bomb})[math.random(2)]
```

My goal is for the bomb to appear or get chosen less often than 'move'. Is this possible?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420502/random-number-generator-with-higher-probabilities-of-giving-low-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. The one of way it can be done is

```
( { move, bomb } )[ math.random( 10 ) <= 7 and 1 or 2 ]
```

You get 70% to choice first element and 30% to choice second one.

If you need choose from 4 element you may use code below

```
local mRandom = math.random
local objects = { 'object1', 'object2', 'object3', 'object4',  } 
local prob = { 10, 30, 60, 100 } -- 10% for object1 20%=30%-10% for object2 30%=60%-30% for object3 and 40%=100%-60% for last object.

local mychoice
math.randomseed( os.time() )


    local rand = mRandom( 100 )

    for i=1, #prob do
        if rand <= prob[i] then
            mychoice = i
            break
        end  
    end
```

Comment: why do you need (10) in bracets?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Yeah sure, I don't understand what [ math.random( 10 ) <= 7 and 1 or 2 ] this part means, the numbers in particular.

Comment: also what should I do if i wanted the probability to increase?(an example if function would be extremely helpful)

Comment: I use [Lua’s and-or as a ternary operator](http://hisham.hm/2011/05/04/luas-and-or-as-a-ternary-operator/) and [classical probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_definition_of_probability). In general you can use `( { move, bomb } )[ math.random( 100 ) <= X and 1 or 2 ]`, where `X` belong to set {1,2,3,...,100}. So you get `X`% to choice first element i.e. `move` and 100%-`X`% to choice second element i.e. `bomb`.

Comment: What if there were more than two choices, let's say for example 4?

Comment: I would use `if-else` for this.

Comment: could you please show the code? I'm finding it difficult to understand. I'd be extremely grateful