# Random number generator, but the chance of getting a higher number is exponentially more rare

Tags: math, lua

I would like to write a random number generator in Lua where the chance of getting a higher number is rarer the higher the number is returned.

I would like it to mimic the following mathematical formula below as close as possible, where the formula below will return the percentage chance of the random number being less than x

```
1/33 + (32/33)*(.01 + .99*(1 - 1/x))
```

I don't really know where to start to be honest, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean with "mimic the following python function as close as possible"? I don't see a Python function in your post. Just some arrithmetic expression which would look the same in Lua. what x variable? the code does not contain any variable named x. please improve your post

Comment: @Piglet sorry had some typos and clarity errors, fixed now

Comment: You want random value from `0.96` to `inf`?

Comment: `local x = 0.96/(1-math.random())`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420502/random-number-generator-with-higher-probabilities-of-giving-low-values